# Library Dependency Resources Overriding the Main Source Set in Android

Tags: android, string, gradle, module, resources

I have Android Library `A` and an Android App `B` that both contains a main and localized `strings.xml`.
The string contents of `A` are just placeholders and should be replaced by the actual contents in `B`.

This used to work before but recently, `A` contents are now overriding in to the final app.

Any specific scenario or change that could have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing this issue only on the Android Studio preview editor, you could try to add the `tools:override="true"` to the string declared into the app

```
<string name="string_key" tools:override="true">String value</string>
```

If this is also a runtime issue, you must be sure that the keys used into the app are really the same used into the library, for each localization used. If you're sure that everything is correct, there could be some misplaced references into the generated indices into the R file, especially if you did some refactor or big changes. You can try to clean the project and run it again. An inspection on the generated R file could help too.

Comment: The tools:override would be "uneconomic" since we have thousands of string generated from a 3rd party tool. (unless we add that in the script also). 

I am thinking this is a Runtime issue. This used to work for a couple of years and suddenly breaking a few months ago. So I was wondering what change could have caused this behavior so I can narrow down the investigation.

Comment: @SergeNinoMartinVillasica I have something similar and it still works great. Maybe the issue you have could be caused by the obfuscation?

Comment: in which specific case the obfuscation could cause this?

Comment: This should not happen for the string resources, but if you have the minifyEnabled in your Gradle files you could try to disable it and run your app. If the issue is not there, probably the obfuscation is the problem